# Яндекс-карты. Как сделать фильтр по объектам недвижимости?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Есть форма где делается выборка недвижимости по набору параметров: тип, район, цена, площадь и т.д. При изменении формы соответственно заново рисуется карта с уже обновлённым набором меток на ней. Есть примеры реализации подобных фильтров? Про [фильтрацию объектов](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_filter) я уже читал, интересует как сделать фильтр по произвольному набору характеристик.

Comment: Фильтруешь у себя в коде свои элементы и передаешь локации того, что отфильтровалось в карту

Comment: А чем фильтры в примере не произвольные?